# Annotation for dynamic Enum

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

the following code (in x.py):

```
from __future__ import annotations
from enum import Enum, auto
from typing import Type

class AEnum(Enum):
    VALUE1 = auto()
    VALUE2 = auto()


SPS_STATES = {
    "pre": "PreReleased",
    "rel": "Released",
    "ret": "Retired",
    "tgt": "Target"
}


SpsState = Enum('SpsState', list(SPS_STATES.values()))


def test_func() -> AEnum:
    return AEnum.VALUE1

def test_func2() -> Type[Enum]:
    return SpsState.Released

print(f'{test_func()}, {type(test_func())}, {[state.name for state in AEnum]}')
print(f'{test_func2()}, {type(test_func2())}, {[state.name for state in SpsState]}')
```

produces the following output (as expected):

```
AEnum.VALUE1, <enum 'AEnum'>, ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2']
SpsState.Released, <enum 'SpsState'>, ['PreReleased', 'Released', 'Retired', 'Target']
```

But when mypy is called with `mypy x.py` is produces

```
x.py:18: error: Second argument of Enum() must be string, tuple, list or dict literal for mypy to determine Enum members  [misc]
x.py:25: error: "type[SpsState]" has no attribute "Released"  [attr-defined]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How do I annotate test_func2 for mypy to be satisfied? I do not want to mention all values of SPS_STATES (as in reality the dict is located in a different file and I want my code to be able to adapt without changing it)

Comment: No, you can’t statically type a dynamically generated enum. If you’re not allowed to touch `SPS_STATES`, you’ll have to write a mypy plugin to recognise static information for this particular `SpsState` enum.

Comment: @dROOOze: Ok, I kind of understand the point, but shouldn't mypy at least not complain about it then? Even if I annotate the return type of test_func2 with Any it will still complain. And the first error (about the second argument of Enum()) is quite wrong, as I explicitly construct a list - and it still complains about the parameter not being a list

Comment: You're right, mypy shouldn't warn when someone is doing dynamic enumeration generation, as it's still valid Python. I guess it's just uncommon these days to do dynamic enum generation; the class-based syntax for enums, typed dictionaries, named tuples, and dataclasses are just overwhelmingly more common. You should request a feature for this at mypy.

Comment: @dROOOze: Hm, as you mention a lot of alternatives: Would you have any suggestion how to rewrite the code using any of the alternatives? It's not as everything is set in stone :-) The dictionary currently is used because users can pass a parameter with the content of the keys of the dict and they are internally mapped to the values of SPS_STATES. If there is a more common way to achieve this, I am happy to adapt the code, too (if it's compatible with Python 3.9).